# force grunt wiredep to inject vendor .min files only

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, bower, wiredep

Hi m using simple in grunt-wiredep  grunt-contrib-watch

```
 grunt.initConfig({
    wiredep: {
        task: {
            src: ['public/**/*.pug']
        }
    }
});
```

it inject file like ,

```
<!--bower:js-->
<script src="../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<!--endbower-->
```

but what i want is to inject .min.js vendor files only.

can anyone help me with simple solution.